# How to save inputs in Koda For Designer

Tags: autoit

I'm really new to AutoIt, I mean like today new, and I'm creating a GUI in Koda form designer. I want to figure out how to save all the input sections in the form so if someone was to open it again it would have their saved inputs.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest file format to use from AutoIt for this are ini files. You've probably seen these as configuration files for programs before, windows used to use them for everything.

The following functions are important: [IniRead](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/IniRead.htm), [IniWrite](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/IniWrite.htm), [GUICtrlRead](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUICtrlRead.htm), [GUICtrlSetData](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUICtrlSetData.htm).

Other types of inputs differ slightly. Checkboxes would require slightly different code, and when using multiline edit controls there are a couple of tricks you can use to get around the ini limitations.

At it's most basic, this is a koda generated form, with a few lines added:

```
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>

Global $sConfigPath = @ScriptDir & "\MySettings.ini"

#Region ### START Koda GUI section ### Form=
Local $Form1 = GUICreate("Form1", 362, 34, 192, 124)
Local $Input1 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 8, 8, 346, 20)
#EndRegion ### END Koda GUI section ###

; Here we can execute code before the window is shown

; Get the value of Input1 from the ini file.
GUICtrlSetData($Input1, IniRead($sConfigPath, "inputs", "Input1", ""))

; Show the window afterwards so it looks a bit tidier
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

While 1
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()

    Switch $nMsg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            ; Note: Exit needs to be changed to ExitLoop
            ; for any code after the loop to execute.
            ExitLoop
    EndSwitch
WEnd

; This code will be executed when the window is closed.

; Writes the value of the $Input1 control to the ini file
IniWrite($sConfigPath, "inputs", "Input1", GUICtrlRead($Input1))
```

That pattern can work for simple forms where you only want to load and save from a single place in the code. When you make more complex GUI's, you'll want to change the loading and saving of inputs to functions, which would allow you to have the normal apply, cancel and ok buttons or even a button to reset to defaults.

And as a final note, it is worth bearing in mind that the AutoIt user base on stackoverflow is very small. Most of our community is on the [AutoIt forums](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/). Questions like this will usually have an answer within 10 minutes, compared to a couple of hours here.

Comment: Thanx I'll use that from now on. I'm just used to coming here 4 python problems thnx again